# Is it acceptable to move questions without answers between sites?

Tags: discussion, migration, cross-posting

I  sometimes wonder where to ask a particular question (on Ubuntu? Unix and Linux? Superuser?) because all of the sites will have great people to help. This is not a common case for me but I already had it happening.

It may be, though, that a question goes unanswered for a while and would be ,  all in all, a better fit for another site.

Is it acceptable, then, to migrate it ? Or move (delete and repost)? Or copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about best-practices on this site, but I would certainly avoid simply moving the questions simply as a way of 'shopping around' for answers.

That said, if the question is a logical fit for more than one site then it might be appropriate - after all I've seen many questions beginning with something along the lines of 'I asked this on X, but it didn't get any answers so I'm reposting it here', and I can't imagine that *moving* a question instead of *creating a new one* would be worse.